# Unable to get username in Azure B2C after successful authentication

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, msal.js

I have a React SPA that communicates with the backend API (Azure Function App). I've created an app registration for both the SPA and the Azure Function App following the steps outlined [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/configure-authentication-sample-spa-app). Both app registrations are hosted in a separate directory from the Azure Function app since I'm using AD B2C. I'm able to successfully authenticate the user and make requests to the backend. I'm using PKCE as the auth protocol and MSAL.js to manage the authentication flow.

I've configured a standard signup/signin policy for which I'm using Local Account as the Identity provider and username as the user id.

Here's what the login screen looks like:
[image]

Here's the relevant code from the SPA which handles auth:

```
const { instance, accounts, inProgress,} = useMsal();
  if (accounts.length > 0) {
    msalInstance
      .acquireTokenSilent({
        account: accounts[0],
        scopes: [
          "https://APP_URI/user_impersonation",
        ],
      })
      .then((token) => {
        console.log("token res is", token);
        console.log("access token is", token);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log("err is", err);
      });
```

Here's the return value from calling `acquireTokenSilent`:

```
{
   "authority":"https://APP_NAMEb2c.b2clogin.com/APP_NAMEb2c.onmicrosoft.com/b2c_1_flow/",
   "uniqueId":"581776f4-6e16-454a-a6ae-ecb49f7f04aa",
   "tenantId":"",
   "scopes":[
      "https://APP_NAMEb2c.onmicrosoft.com/reg_api/user_impersonation"
   ],
   "account":{
      "homeAccountId":"581776f4-6e16-454a-a6ae-ecb49f7f04aa-b2c_1_flow.07232d62-7285-4737-97eb-87f0f9b7c38e",
      "environment":"APP_NAMEb2c.b2clogin.com",
      "tenantId":"",
      "username":"testUser@gmail.com",
      "localAccountId":"581776f4-6e16-454a-a6ae-ecb49f7f04aa",
      "name":"unknown",
      "idTokenClaims":{
         "exp":1663191498,
         "nbf":1663187898,
         "ver":"1.0",
         "iss":"https://APP_NAMEb2c.b2clogin.com/07232d62-7285-4737-97eb-87f0f9b7c38e/v2.0/",
         "sub":"581776f4-6e16-454a-a6ae-ecb49f7f04aa",
         "aud":"473fe4d9-260b-46ad-9ad1-f4c4a4f211e6",
         "nonce":"65c7ec69-2837-4bdf-b9e3-ae38dbb19c48",
         "iat":1663187898,
         "auth_time":1663187896,
         "name":"unknown",
         "emails":[
            "testUser@gmail.com"
         ],
         "tfp":"B2C_1_flow",
         "at_hash":"qOHPceVj3fEhGGlRq6xh4g"
      }
   },
   "idToken":"TD_TOKEN",
   "idTokenClaims":{
      "exp":1663191498,
      "nbf":1663187898,
      "ver":"1.0",
      "iss":"https://APP_NAMEb2c.b2clogin.com/07232d62-7285-4737-97eb-87f0f9b7c38e/v2.0/",
      "sub":"581776f4-6e16-454a-a6ae-ecb49f7f04aa",
      "aud":"473fe4d9-260b-46ad-9ad1-f4c4a4f211e6",
      "nonce":"65c7ec69-2837-4bdf-b9e3-ae38dbb19c48",
      "iat":1663187898,
      "auth_time":1663187896,
      "name":"unknown",
      "emails":[
         "testUser@gmail.com"
      ],
      "tfp":"B2C_1_flow",
      "at_hash":"qOHPceVj3fEhGGlRq6xh4g"
   },
   "accessToken":"ACCESS_TOKEN",
   "fromCache":true,
   "expiresOn":"2022-09-14T21:38:18.000Z",
   "correlationId":"9c71acbb-7ed4-4beb-a282-71ec7d924bd8",
   "extExpiresOn":"2022-09-14T21:38:18.000Z",
   "familyId":"",
   "tokenType":"Bearer",
   "state":"",
   "cloudGraphHostName":"",
   "msGraphHost":"",
   "fromNativeBroker":false
}
```

As you can see, the `username` property has the emailAddress as it's value and not the actual username.

I've not been able to find concrete guidance on how to get the username. The one resource I found said that UserPrincipleName(UPN) is an optional claim and to add this value in the authToken I [should add UPN as an optional claim](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-optional-claims) in the token configuration tab, which is not available in B2C AD. I would love to get some guidance on what I'm doing wrong as getting the username should not be this hard, right ?

**Edit 1:**  I can confirm that the username has been set; in the image below the username is denoted by User Principle Name:

[image]

Comment: According to the [official sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-javascript-react-tutorial/blob/main/1-Authentication/2-sign-in-b2c/SPA/src/App.jsx#L28), user name may gather from , see screenshot here 
   https://i.stack.imgur.com/cF6qH.png

Comment: And the `name` property showed `unknown`, so is it possible that you haven't set the user name for your test user?

Comment: @TinyWang, The name property was "unkown" because the name for that particular user was not set, I've updated the name to "Test username" and now the name value is filled correctly. Unfortunately this has no bearing on the user principle name.

Answer (score 1):

The `username` property in MSAL's [AccountInfo](https://azuread.github.io/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/ref/modules/_azure_msal_common.html#accountinfo) object is populated by the `email` claim in the ID token. The `email` claim will be an array, and if there are multiple emails, MSAL will only use the first one as username.

To receive UserPrincipleName (UPN) in the ID token, you'll need to set the user attributes in your B2C tenant. Unfortunately this doesn't seem to be possible with standard user-flows, so you'll need to build a custom policy and sign-in with that instead. See for more: [User profile attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/user-profile-attributes#azure-ad-user-resource-type)

Comment: I see that you actually work at MS AD!  Is there a reason why the username property is not available as part of the id token ?  Thank you for your help!

Comment: No worries! You just need to configure your user flow to return the email addresses of the user (which is what username field is populated with). Check out the FAQ [here](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/lib/msal-browser/FAQ.md#why-is-getaccountbyusername-returning-null-even-though-im-signed-in) for more

Comment: username actually gets populated from the emails claim not email.  If using OpenIdConnect to Azure AD from Azure B2C you would add the following to your outputclaims in the technical profile
            <OutputClaim  ClaimTypeReferenceId="otherMails" />  

then in the SignUpOrSignin policy add the following to the RelyingParty TechnicalProfile output claim

<OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="otherMails" PartnerClaimType="emails"/>